# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:4.5.6:sonar (default-cli) on project smallcell: Java heap space

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, heap-memory, upgrade, sonarqube-scan

After Upgrade to **Sonar version 5.5** we have an error in analyzing project.
We run project with maven sonar plugin in Jenkins.

**Error :-**

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:4.5.6:sonar (default-cli) on
>   project smallcell: Java heap space -> [Help 1]

**In Jenkins console output:**

```
*Exception in thread "CLEANUP_MANAGER" `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`: Java heap space
12:12:31    at `java.util.ArrayList`.<init>(`ArrayList.java:152`)
12:12:31    at `com.persistit.CleanupManager.poll(CleanupManager.java:166)`
12:12:31    at `com.persistit.CleanupManager.runTask(CleanupManager.java:88)`
12:12:33    at com.persistit.IOTaskRunnable.run(IOTaskRunnable.java:144)
12:12:33    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
12:12:33 Exception in thread "JOURNAL_FLUSHER" Exception in thread "Report about progress of Javascript analyzer" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
12:12:33    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
12:12:33    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
...
...*
```

We tried to enlarge all parameters related to heap size in `sonar.properties` file, wrapper file in Sonar and also JVM OPTS, node JVM parameters in Jenkins.

Nothing helped.

Comment: Did you try setting [MAVEN_OPTS](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-Troubleshooting)? To which value?

Comment: @Pierre-Yves 
Yes, we tried. It did not help. Only after we excluded .js files from analyze we back to SUCCESSFUL ANALYSE, because Sonar failed on analyzing .js files larger then 1M. Do you know what may be solution for big .js files?

Comment: To which value did you set MAVEN_OPTS? You should either allocate enough memory or exclude big files from the analysis.

Comment: We tried till  -Xmx6144m

Comment: Which version of the JS plugin do you use? I can analyse [tinymce.js](http://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.js) which is 1.2MB with -Xmx512m.

Comment: We failed with both 2.9 and 2.13 versions.

Comment: Can you try analyzing tinymce.js?